# Htaccess Redirection without changing browser url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

When users come to my site, they use this format of url ("demo" has no importance here) :
**https://example.com/page/demo-558**

My system may redirect it to this format
**https://example.com/?view=test&page=658**

But I don't want the users to see URL change in the browser, it must be invisible.
I searched for hours but nothing seems to works !
Here is my current rule :

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.+)-([0-9]+)$ /index.php?view=test&page=$2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How should the browser display a dynamic page with parameters without 'knowing' the parameter?

I think you are not searching for a (transparent) rewrite, more for a reverse (not transparent) proxy. The URL will be handled between http server and proxy, the browser gets the 'simplyfied' URL.

1. Browser send to Server: /page/demo-558
2. Server rewrite to /?view=test&page=658
3. Server delivers content to ReverseProxy with /?view=test&page=658
4. ReverseProxy delivers content to browser with /page/demo-558

The ReverseProxy is part of the http-Server

Explained with pictures: https://www.akadia.com/services/apache_redirect.html